# Found a real number $t$ such that $(14 + 5 \sqrt{3})(5 - \sqrt{3})\sqrt{8- 2 \sqrt{15}}= t \sqrt{2}$

Tags: calculus, radicals

In order to find the real number $t $ such that $A=(14 + 5 \sqrt{3})(5 - \sqrt{3})\sqrt{8- 2 \sqrt{15}}= t \sqrt{2}$ 
I have already compute this two expression 
\begin{align*}
a=5+\sqrt{3} & = \sqrt{28 +  10\sqrt{3}} \\
b=5-\sqrt{3} & = \sqrt{28 - 10\sqrt{3}}
\end{align*}
because $a^2 = 28 +  10\sqrt{3}$ and $b^2=28 -  10\sqrt{3}$.
Then $2A=(28 + 10 \sqrt{3})(5 - \sqrt{3})\sqrt{8- 2 \sqrt{15}}= a^2b \sqrt{8- 2 \sqrt{15}}$. 
Additional calculus get me anywhere. Is there a charitable sool to give some help.
Thank in advance for your comprehension.

Comment: The question statement doesn't seem to be complete, as $t=(14 + 5 \sqrt{3})(5 - \sqrt{3})\sqrt{8- 2 \sqrt{15}}/\sqrt{2}$ trivially answers it.

Comment: How about $(14+5\sqrt3)(5-\sqrt3)\sqrt{4-\sqrt{15}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$8-2\sqrt{15}=\cdots=(\sqrt5-\sqrt3)^2$$

We know for real $a,$ $$\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$$

which $=a,$ if $a\ge0$

else $=-a$

Now just multiply out

Answer (score 0):

i don't know exactly what the Problem here is dividing by $\sqrt{2}$ and simplifying we get
$$t={\frac {55\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {5}}{2}}-{\frac {55\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}}{2}
}+11/2\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {5}\sqrt {3}-{\frac {33\,\sqrt {2}}{2}}
$$

Comment: The problem is to deduce from the values of $a$ and $b$ that there exist a real number $t$ such that $A = t \sqrt{2}$.